# "undefined reference to `ceilf'"

Tags: c, eclipse

Simple question.  I'm importing code previously written by someone else into eclipse.  I am getting the error:

```
"undefined reference to `ceilf'"
```

when I use `ceilf`.  It appears to me that `ceilf` is suppose to be contained in the math.h library which is included in my file.  However, when I open up the /usr/include/math.h file I don't see a ceilf method defined.  In fact as far as I can tell none of the math.h files on my redhat deployment have a `ceilf` method.  Any idea where the wayward `ceilf` method is defined?  Since this code works and even compiles elsewhere the issue has to be with my configuration rather then the code itself.

ps. I can use the regular `ceil` method.  I've considered just switching to it, but it would be less efficent in a critical path of the program.  Yes I know premature optimization is evil, but I'm asking as much out of curiousity as to why I would have the error anyways.  I can't see why my `math.h` files wouldn't defile it.

EDIT::
thank you for explaining why I can't find the `ceilf` function, I understand that problem.  However, I don't know how to appease eclipse.  I've tried setting the compiler option to use **std=c99** as suggested and it doesn't remove the error.  In fact I thought eclipse was just using my **Makefile** to do the build, and the make file doesn't throw the exception.  Is there something I can do to cause the editor to realize I have the file defined?

Comment: `ceilf` conforms to C99. If you are compiling against an older standard, that function will not be there. Try compiling with -`std=c99`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ceilf` is part of the math library, so you need to link with `-lm` to use it.  Just `#include <math.h>` is not enough.

Comment: I already checked, the math.h file does not seem to have a definithion of ceilf despite it supposedly being part of math.h.  that's what started the question

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual page:

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       ceilf(), ceill():
           _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600 ||
           _ISOC99_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L;
           or cc -std=c99
```

Try setting the standard to C99 in your compiler or enabling one of these feature-test macros.

Also make sure you're linking with `-lm` or the appropriate switch for your platform and compiler to link the math library.

Comment: This solves the problem for compiler errors, but "undefined reference" is a linker error which occurs when not linking with `libm` on some systems.

Comment: I have tried this, it didn't work.  also, eclipse is only running make to compile everything; which is part of what has me confused.  if I make this program by myself in the command line it runs fine and builds, but if eclipse does the build (which as I understand it just means calling the same make file) I get the exception?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't necessarily use the Makefile that's in the build directory.  Check the Build Configuration for the current project (in Eclipse).